# GPLライセンスにおいて不特定多数のユーザへのサービス提供に関して

Tags: ライセンス, gpl

wordpress（GPLライセンス）において、下記のケースは違反にあたりますでしょうか？
もしくは、ソース開示が必要なケースにあたりますでしょうか？

・wordpressベースで改変を行い、db,apiのみを利用するCMSを構築し自社サーバに設置。
　有料で不特定多数のユーザにCMS提供